# Squid proxy slow via PS4?

Tags: squid

This is my config: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sRQCkFy4dy/

The system running Squid Proxy is a native Ubuntu 20.04 on Ryzen 3200G/8gb/120GBSSD.

When I use it to connect my PS4 to the internet, downloads are extremely slow. I am not sure how to diagnose this, can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of thins that can go wrong.

- How fast are the exact same downloads on the Ubuntu-Machine itself?
- What does your /var/log/squid/*log say?
- PSN Downloads are (usually) multistream-connections, I suspect Squid is just taking HTTP requests (and nothing like bittorrent)

Definately have an eye on the logs. Usually the PS4 is the one requesting more (or less) parts. The proxy should answer to those very fast and take more than one at a time.

Comment: Downloads via the Ubuntu system max out at 380mbps. it's the PS4 that's slow. I haven't looked at the log, I'll take a look now :) no settings I can change?

Comment: "Definately have an eye on the logs. Usually the PS4 is the one requesting more (or less) parts. The proxy should answer to those very fast and take more than one at a time." so what should I do?

Comment: This is a picture of uGet on ubuntu and downloading a test file whilst connected to the proxy: https://i.postimg.cc/2y857yK0/Screenshot-from-2020-06-07-15-30-14.png

Comment: Grep the URL (maybe the whole request) and download it by yourself. If it's the same speed, it's not the proxys fault.